# set AppleLanguages doesn't work on ios 7?

Tags: ios, ios7, nsuserdefaults, ios7.1

I need to set the default language in my app. I use the set `AppleLanguages` technique in my `main.m`. But it doesn't work under iOS 7, though work in iOS 6. Is there any workaround for this?

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@[@"ru"] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: Does it works if you restart the app ?

Comment: Will it work if you set `AppleLanguages` as a launch argument as described here: http://nshipster.com/launch-arguments-and-environment-variables ?

Comment: @vokilam: Actually what I want to achieve is a default fall back language, so need to do some checking before setting the language. The launch argument method seems not fit this situation?

Comment: @Antzi: it does work after restarting the app, but can I make it work without restarting?

Comment: @vokilam about launch arguments: You can't provide launch arguments to an app on the store, so it's not really useful if not only for development

Answer (score 1):

This code work for me on iOS 7
I use it to set Hebrew as the default lang

```
NSMutableArray* arr = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"] mutableCopy];
[arr removeObject:targetLang];
[arr insertObject:targetLang atIndex:0];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:arr forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your main.m this way

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setObject:@[@"ru"] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
        [defaults synchronize];
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([/*Nameofyourdelegate*/class]));
    }
}
```

I'm still investigating on it, see [Set default language at first run IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22448407/set-default-language-at-first-run-ios)